# Possible to have many web apps under a single app service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are trying to deploy some web services and sites to Azure. We are having some issues getting them to work and Microsoft set us up on a call with some consultants. They suggested that you can only have one web app per app service. We have 4 sites/services and many customers so this would take a lot of configuration if true.

Please can you let us know if it is possible to have a number of web apps under a single app service.

Comment: Yes, you can have as many as you want as long as your worker VMs can take it (e.g. One App Service Plan spanning 3 large S3 instances). I would also like to learn who those consultants are, if you can't share publicly we'll find a way. You should really share this publicly.

Comment: @evilSnobu Isn't "S3" Amazon Web Services AWS only? Can you combine Azure VMs and AWS S3 storage?

Comment: S3 as in Standard plan Large instance, S1 and S2 for small and medium. If by combining you mean can i have my disk in S3 and mount it over in Azure then no. If you simply mean can i call an S3 bucket from Azure, absolutely yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely possible to have many apps in a single plan. The App Service plan defines the boundaries of the CPU, memory etc. of the underlying reosurce. With that, each pricing plan has its own limitations, also for number of apps in each. Most important thing to remember though is that all apps under a given single plan are using the same resource, so if one app has a lot of traffic, this will impact the available compute power for the other apps. This can be solved with setting auto-scale rules to add instances, but I would suggest isolating apps that you expect to have heavier loads and grouping the smaller ones to save cost.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can have multiple web app host within single app service depending on the plan you have selected.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely you can! I have more apps under the same plan.

[image]